# (Java) Iterating over a Vector<String[]>, why is .next() an Object, not a String[]?

Tags: java, casting, iterator

In Java, when you iterator over a `Vector<String[]>`, why is `.next()` an `Object` that needs to be casted to `String[]`, to use each element as a `String[]`?

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
    Iterator itr = getIdAndName().iterator();
    while( itr.hasNext() ) {
        String[] stringArray = (String[])itr.next();
        String id = stringArray[0];
        String name = stringArray[1];
        System.out.println(id + ": " + name);
    }
```

`getIdAndName()` returns `Vector<String[]>`.

Comment: To my knowledge, it doesn't give an `Object` but a `String[]`.  Please post sample code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It isn't.  The only thing I can think of is you're not typing your iterator, i.e. you're doing this:

```
Vector<String[]> vector;
Iterator it = vector.iterator();
Object obj = it.next();
```

when you should be doing:

```
Vector<String[]> vector;
Iterator<String[]> it = vector.iterator();
String[] next = it.next();
```

Well, in most cases you don't actually need the iterator directly, so you could just use:

```
Vector<String[]> vector;
for (String[] element : vector) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing. `Iterator itr` specifically when I should be doing `Iterator<String[]>  itr`. I did not know this.

Comment: since I have your attention, how could/should I sort this array by one of the elements in the `String[]`?

Answer (score 3):

The `iterator()` method returns an `Iterator<String[]>` when called on a variable whose declared type is `Vector<String[]>`.

I suspect that you are calling it on a variable that is declared as `Vector` or `Vector<?>` or something else.  Or maybe you are assigning the iterator to an `Iterator` or `Iterator<?>` variable instead of an `Iterator<String[]>`.  Obviously, this is just conjecture, because you didn't show us the source code.

(Note that it is the *declared* type of the *variable* that determines whether a cast is required ... not the actual type of the instance.)

Comment: +1 for noting that whether or not a cast is required is determined by static types, not by the class that an object actually possesses at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

When you get iterator from your vector, example `vector.iterator();` your iterator should have parameterized. This way, the iterator will know the object that it stored is of type String[], if you do not tell iterator of the type it stored, it will have to resort to the object.

When you properly parameterized the type, for example  `Iterator<String[]> iter = vector.iterator();` , and then the iteration over iter will not need to be cast explicitly.

Please refer here about [generic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html).

Answer (score -2):

When you iterate over a Vector, you are using an implementation of the Iterator interface. By DEFINITION, the Iterator interface returns an Object when its next() method is called. You can see this definition here -

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

So it doesn't matter what you iterate over, the Iterator will always return an Object when you call its next() method.

And by the way, .next() does not HAVE to be casted to a String[]. It is just the case that in your specific case the Vector contains String[] as its elements, and therefore they are casted to String[] in order to use them.

Comment: This is not true for Java 5+ with generics.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html, which shows that `Iterator` has been retrofitted with generics to become `Iterator<E>`.